# Не устанавливается Apache 2.4

Tags: apache

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\Server\bin\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k install
[Tue Jul 25 09:52:32.666693 2017] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 7056:tid 516] AH00433: Apache2.4: Service is already installed.
```

Хотя я ничего не устанавливал

Comment: Как удалить вопрос?

Comment: В справке есть ответ на ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions